# How to map corresponding data with np.fft to positive values of np.fft.fftfreq

Tags: python, arrays, fft

I am using np.fft and np.fft.fftfreq. When I use np.fft.fftfreq, it produces a conjugate symmetric array of frequency values as expected.

For plotting purposes, I am only taking the positive values from this array. How do I create an array of the appropriate corresponding values of the signal that has had np.fft applied to it? That way, I can plot (positive) frequency on the x-axis and the corresponding Fourier transformed signal on the y-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing this task, I use the following function:

```py
def get_fft(y, frequency):
    y_fft = np.fft.fft(y)
    y_fft = np.abs(y_fft)
    x_fft = np.fft.fftfreq(len(y_fft), frequency)
    x_fft = x_fft[:len(x_fft) // 2]
    y_fft = y_fft[:len(y_fft) // 2]

    return x_fft, y_fft
```

Does that help you?